# T-SQL Select statement returns zero rows when using IN

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having some trouble with a t-sql select query in C#. The query is as follows:

```
@"SELECT * FROM 
 (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as row_number
 FROM [mytable]) t0
 WHERE row_number BETWEEN @skip and @take
 AND
 uploadDate IN (@years) 
 AND NOT photoId IN (@shownPhotos) 
 ORDER BY NEWID()";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@skip", SqlDbType.Int).Value = skip;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@take", SqlDbType.Int).Value = take;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@shownPhotos", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = shownPhotos;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@years", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = years;
```

The method takes four parameters: skip count, take count, shownPhotos (commaseparated string which contains photo ids), years (comma separated string which contains the years to show the photos from)

So basically I want it to return photos from my database which matches any of the years from the commaseparated string and which are not already shown.

The problem (I think) is that my parameters are strings, so they are intepreted as '1234,567,890' and '2011,2012'. When running the query in the SQL server management tool without the 's it works fine.

Anyone got a workaround for this? :-)

Thanks a lot in advance!

**Updated code:**

```
// Create datatables
            DataTable yearsTable = new DataTable();
            yearsTable.Columns.Add("YearID", typeof(string));
            yearsTable.Columns.Add("Year", typeof(string));

            foreach(string year in years.Split(','))
                yearsTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { year, year });

            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(GlobalSettings.DbDSN))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText =
                        @"SELECT * FROM 
                          (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as row_number
                          FROM [mytable]) t0
                          WHERE row_number BETWEEN @skip and @take
                          AND
                          uploadedDate IN (@years)                               
                          ORDER BY NEWID()";

                    SqlParameter skipParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skip", skip);
                    skipParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;

                    SqlParameter takeParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@take", take);
                    takeParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;

                    SqlParameter yearsParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@years", yearsTable);
                    yearsParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                    yearsParam.TypeName = "dbo.MyTableType";


                    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();                        
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, your `IN` are being interpreted as "is in this set of 1 value", i.e. what you have is identical to:

```
AND uploadDate = @years
AND NOT photoId = @shownPhotos
```

evaluated as regular string equality on the strings `'1234,567,890'` and `'2011,2012'`. At the TSQL level, a common trick is to write a "split" UDF that separates a single varchar into multiple row values. Many libraries have tools for this too; for example, in ["dapper"](http://nuget.org/packages/Dapper) we adding a syntax trick to pre-expand them, i.e.

```
int[] years = {2011,2012};
int[] shownPhotos = {1234,567,890};
int skip = 0, take = 10;
var rows = connection.Query<RowType>(
  @"SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as row_number
   FROM [mytable]) t0
   WHERE row_number BETWEEN @skip and @take
   AND uploadDate IN @years
   AND NOT photoId IN @shownPhotos
   ORDER BY NEWID()", new {skip,take,years,shownPhotos}).ToList();
```

Note the lack of brackets next to `IN`, which we interpret as "figure this out yourself" to the library, which then does exactly what you want. It will actually be evaluated as:

```
   AND uploadDate IN (@years0,@years1)
   AND NOT photoId IN (@shownPhotos0,@shownPhotos1,@shownPhotos2)
```

where `@years0` has the value `2011`, `@years1` has the value `2012`, etc.

Comment: I like that solution Marc, but the thing is that I am working with strings here and not int :-/ So I guess that's not an option?

Comment: @bomortenson not a problem - use string[] instead of int[] - it'll work fine.

Comment: Oh, so I have to install dapper to do this? :)

Comment: @bomortensen it isn't part of the framework, indeed. It is freely available as a dll on NuGet, or you can just pull the single .cs file from google-code and include that in your project.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I just installed it via NuGet :) Getting the following exception when running my query, though: A parameterless default constructor or one matching signature is required for System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RowType materialization

Comment: @bomortensen the `RowType` in my example was meant to be some custom class of yours that looks like the columns coming back from the table... For example `class Customer { public int Id {get;set;} public string Name {get;set;}}`. If you don't want to do that, just take away the `<RowType>` completely, and you can use the `dynamic` API instead. Ether way, you then have access to `rows[0].Id`, `rows[0].Name` etc. Your "what the table looks like" wasn't in the question, so I couldn't give a full example of that bit.

Answer (score 2):

You are right in your evaluation of the problem - @shownphotos and @years will be interpreted as a single string.

Table valued parameters are the answer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx

(Well done on parameterising your SQL statement - don't be tempted to work around this issue by concatenating a SQL statement from strings!)

Comment: Hi podiluska, thanks for your input :-) I'm not sure about the difference from my current parameterising to the examples in the link, but I might just have tired eyes at the moment ;-)

Comment: @bomortensen The key is the Parameter data type `SqlDbType.Structured` - see the section "Passing a Table-Valued Parameter to a Parameterized SQL Statement"

Comment: @podiluska: thanks a lot :-) I tried to set SqlDbType.Structured, but then got an exception: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a IEnumerable`1. Not sure what that means to be honest :-/

Comment: You should convert your string into a DataTable first.

Comment: Forgive me my slowlyness, I'm used to use Entity Framework and not T-SQL ;-) I have updated my question with new code which uses datatables, but I'm getting the following exception: @shownPhotos must have a valid type name

Comment: You need to create a type on the server (see the "Creating Table-Valued Parameter Types" section), and set the TypeName property of the two parameters accordingly.

Comment: I simply dont get it .. I have created a TableType now with the two columns "YearID" (dunno if that's needed) and "Year" but I keep getting the following exception: Must declare the scalar variable "@years".. I've updated my question with new code..

Comment: @bomortensen @Years is now a table so your IN should be `IN (Select YearID from @Years)` or you can join to it.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're comparing the entire date against a set of years.

Why not extract just the year and compare?

```
@"SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as row_number
FROM [mytable]) t0
WHERE row_number BETWEEN @skip and @take
AND
DATEPART(yyyy,uploadDate) IN (@years) 
AND NOT photoId IN (@shownPhotos) 
ORDER BY NEWID()";
```

Read more on DATEPART here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datepart.asp

Comment: You may need to type cast the DATEPART result to VARCHAR to get it working.